# Line perpendicular to two other lines - data sufficiency

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been given this problem but I'm not sure there is enough information to solve it, I was wondering if anyone could verify that. Thank you.

--

Let r be a line going through the points $(1,2,-1)$ and $(2,1,0)$ and let s be a line going through the points $(4,1,0)$ and $(2,1,-1)$.

Find the equation of a line t, perpendicular to both lines and common to both (it "touches" both of them).

--

You could find the vector of line t by cross product from the lines r and s, but how would you find the exact equation of the line? It doesn't say that the line t goes through neither of the points mentioned.

Thank you,

Bruno

Comment: The two given lines will have two parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$. The unknown perpendicular line will have an unknown parameter t and an unknown point A it goes through. If line meets the two given lines you can write down an equation for each intersection point. One involves $\lambda$, A and a value $t_1$ of t. The other involves $\mu$, A and a value $t_2$. Subtract these equations to give an equation involving $\lambda$, $\mu$ and $p = t_2 - t_1$. This equation can be solved for $|lambda$ and $\mu$ giving you two points your line goes through.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

There is enough information. Unless two lines are parallel, there is a unique line of minimum length that joins them.

If $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ denote the direction vectors of the two given lines, then you are correct that the minimum-length line is in the direction of the cross product $\mathbf{W} = \mathbf{U} \times \mathbf{V}$.

The first line is defined by the point $\mathbf{P} = (1,2,-1)$ and the vector $\mathbf{U}=(1,-1,1)$, so its equation can be written $\mathbf{A}(s) = \mathbf{P} + s\mathbf{U}$. Similarly, the second line has equation $\mathbf{B}(t) = \mathbf{Q}+t\mathbf{V}$, where $\mathbf{Q} = (4,1,0)$ and $\mathbf{V}=(-2,0,-1)$.

To achieve minumum distance, the "joining" line $\mathbf{A}(s) - \mathbf{B}(t)$ must be perpendicular to the given two lines, so:
$$
\left[(\mathbf{A}(s) - \mathbf{B}(t) \right] \cdot \mathbf{U} = 0
$$
$$
\left[(\mathbf{A}(s) - \mathbf{B}(t) \right] \cdot \mathbf{V} = 0
$$
Substituting for $\mathbf{A}(s)$ and $\mathbf{B}(t)$ and rearranging, we get
$$
s(\mathbf{U} \cdot \mathbf{U}) - t(\mathbf{U} \cdot \mathbf{V}) = 
\mathbf{U} \cdot (\mathbf{Q} - \mathbf{P}) 
$$
$$
s(\mathbf{U} \cdot \mathbf{V}) - t(\mathbf{V} \cdot \mathbf{V}) = 
\mathbf{V} \cdot (\mathbf{Q} - \mathbf{P}) 
$$
These equations have a unique solution unless the original two lines are parallel. If $s_0$ and $t_0$ are the solutions, then the closest points of the two lines are then $\mathbf{A}(s_0)$ and $\mathbf{B}(t_0)$.

Comment: Thats great @bubba, as soon as I solve the problem I'll post it here for your final approval. Thank you.

Comment: @bubba How exactly do you read/find the points of intersection of the line onto A & B from this? Or at very least how do you find the whole line equation of the line orthogonal to both A & B?

Comment: @JackOfBlades:  Please see the addition (the last sentence).